# Selenium RC got stuck at "Checking resource aliases"

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am new to selenium, I got a problem when running selenium RC.

Actually, I have recorded one script via `selenium IDE` and saved it as `test.html` and I am able to run the script via `selenium IDE` but when I try to run the script via `selenium RC` it gets stuck at some point and displays the following message in the console "Checking resource aliases"

**command for running the script via command prompt:**

`java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "www.google.com" "test.html" -port 4445`

Let me know the exact reason why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should save your tests as a Test Suite also.

At the end you will have two HTML files, the Test Suite and the Test Case (or more if you want).
The command java -jar .... to run selenium, with the -htmlSuite parameter, takes an HTML Test Suite, not a Test Case.

I had the same problem and after passing the Test Suite as the parameter worked as charm.

Answer (score 3):

**Step-1:** Please create a new html file TestSuite.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Application Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table> 
        <tr><td><b>Suite Of Tests</b></td></tr> 
        <tr><td><a href="./OPSTest.html">Test Example</a></td></tr>
    </table> 
</body>
```

**Step-2:** Rename `OPSTest.html` to your file name `test.html`.

**Step-3:** Run this command in command line

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "www.google.com" "TestSuite.html" -port 4445
```