# Issue running Selenium IDE test suite using Selenium Standalone server

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am try to follow following references to run the selenium IDE test suites on standalone server . My ultimate purpose is to run headless data-driven tests on ubuntu.

[Selenium RC with DataDriven](https://maryannmp.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-rc-html-tests/)

[Running Tests from command line](http://www.jadeliquid.com/blogs/2011/running-selenium-tests-from-the-command-line.php)

[Selenium Headless tests on Ubuntu](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2012/11/19/installing-selenium-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu/)

So after looking into these tutorials I have setup very simple test suite and trying to run from command line e.g

```
 java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar  -userExtensions user-extensions.js -htmlSuite "*firefox" http://google.com ./suite.html ./out/firefox-results.html
```

**Output**

```
org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
10:16:54.164 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-462
10:16:54.164 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8 x86_64
10:16:54.178 INFO - v2.39.0, with Core v2.39.0. Built from revision ff23eac
10:16:54.250 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: MAC
10:16:54.336 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
10:16:54.338 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
10:16:54.339 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
10:16:54.340 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
10:16:54.340 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
10:16:54.406 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@5ff06dc3
10:16:54.407 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
10:16:54.413 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
10:16:54.414 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@4ca31e1b
jar:file:/Users/myname/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
10:16:54.580 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
10:16:55.946 INFO - Launching Firefox...
10:16:57.246 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

It does open two firefox windows and hangs there after `INFO - Checking Resource aliases`

It does not matter If I skip `-userExtensions user-extensions.js`,it gives same output , show two popup windows and hangs there. The firefox popup window shows test suite loaded successfully , but not command is executed further.

I wonder if I need to run/configure sth else

**Example Test Suite and Test Case:**

1. [suite.html](http://jsfiddle.net/u2qLk/2/)
2. [case_a.html](http://jsfiddle.net/9BHU8/1/)
3. Command

   `java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar  -htmlSuite "*firefox" http://www.google.com suite.html firefox-results.html`

   Tested Under:

   A) OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8 x86_64 /java version "1.6.0_65"

   B) OS: Windows 7 / java version : 1.7.0_02

**Hacks Tried without any luck**:

A) [Removing xml tag](http://seleniumforum.forumotion.net/t233-selenium-rc-stuck-in-checking-resource-aliases)

B) [.html file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722227/selenium-rc-got-stucks-at-checking-resource-aliases)

Comment: So, Are you try [this tutorial](https://maryannmp.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-rc-html-tests/) and doesn't work? Are you create suite.html with Seleneium IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question got much attention and needed a proper solution, which I found this way:

First of all we need proper addons to setup headless tests

## Getting the right addons

I am already using following selenium IDE addons

1. datadriven v0.2
2. flowcontrol v08
3. includecommand 1.3

What I need is respective selenium addons which work with **selenium core server** for which I need

1. datadriven_v0.2-core.js
2. flowcontrol ( goto_sel08.js)
3. includecommand ( includeCommand_2.3.js) [origional source](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/circabc/automatisation/selenium/extensions/includeCommand_2.3/user-extensions.js.includeCommand)

   since openqa.org does not maintain these addons anymore (probably broken or so) You have to use [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/) to get js files ( no luck with zip attachments). e g  [flowcontrol in wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130323001206/http://wiki.openqa.org/spaces/listattachmentsforspace.action?key=SEL)

Since I have done this already and created a gist with some fixes

1. [datadriven_v0.2-core.js](https://gist.github.com/sakhunzai/55d2b5061b9b5aade40c)
2. [flowcontrol ( goto_sel08.js)](https://gist.github.com/sakhunzai/1c664d7a54410e997777)
3. [includeCommand_2.3.js](https://gist.github.com/sakhunzai/d733504d8dca105f5ebf)
4. [user-extension.js](https://gist.github.com/sakhunzai/cd3de1ea080e9d42cd00) ( all three of above combined)

## Setting up Headless Tests

a) install xvfb ( X Vritual Frame Buffer and firefox )

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic xvfb x11-apps  firefox
```

b) create xvfb init script /var/init.d/xvfb

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "`basename $0` {start|stop}"
  exit
fi

case "$1" in
start)
  /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 &
;;
stop)
  killall Xvfb
;;
esac
```

c) add to startup script:

```
sudo update-rc.d xvfb defaults
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/xvfb
```

d) start the xvfb

```
/etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

e) Setup selenium Tests (you can put test anywhere)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/SeleniumTests   && cd /usr/local/SeleniumTests
```

checkout/copy your html tests to /usr/local/SeleniumTests

f) create alias to test directory (config file 'selenium_alias')
   (only allow from localhost)

```
<IfModule alias_module>
       Alias  /SeleniumTests/  /usr/local/SeleniumTests/
  </IfModule>
  <Directory "/usr/local/SeleniumTests/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
   </Directory>

sudo mv SeleniumTests/selenium_alias /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable
sudo a2ensite selenium
sudo service apache2 restart
```

g) update selenium tests data
 (/usr/local/SeleniumTests/tests/data)
 e.g change test username/password and baseUrl to test app (which I have in xml file)

h) Download Seleninum Server jar file

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/selenium/ 
sudo wget http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -o /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar
```

i) Run the headless /Selenese  Tests

```
export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar   -htmlSuite *firefox https://localhost "/usr/local/SeleniumTests/tests/my_app_smoke_testing_suite.html" "firefox-results.html" -trustAllSSLCertificates  -ensureCleanSession -port 5561 -userExtensions /usr/local/SeleniumTests/addons/user-extensions.js
```

**Note**  I have my selenium addons setup under /usr/local/SeleniumTests/addons

Some of the the steps might not be desirable in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <Selenium server location path>java -jar <selenium-server name>.jar –htmlSuite "*<browser_name>" "<Url of base website>" "<Path of html_suite>" "<Path to store reports>"
```

> selenium-server name  :- selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.xx was used.
>
> browser_name      :- "iexplore" for Internet Explorer/ "firefox" for
>   Mozilla Firefox
>
> Url of base website       :- Base URL.
>
> Path of html_suite        :- The path of test suite you used to save file
>   (E.g.:"C:\TestSuite.htm", assuming "C" drive as location you used
>   to save test suite).
>
> Path to store reports    :-The path you want to save your test result
>   into (E.g.:"C:\TestResult.htm", assuming "C" drive as location you
>   used to save test result).

Comment: thanks @Wasi, I have come around most of the issues I encountered.Its long story I ll write a detail note about that. Its much deeper than its .

Comment: @sakhunzai: oops didn't notice "headless data-driven tests on ubuntu"

Comment: how to give timeout and speed as slow and auto= false?

Answer (score 1):

Some commands are not working in Firefox:

> The user extension goto_sel_ide that defines the While and Goto
>   commands does not  work with Selenium RC. Include the user extension
>   goto_sel08.js instead.

From: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC

I think you are following these steps from [this page](https://maryannmp.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-rc-html-tests/):

1. Download goto_sel08.js
2. Download the 1.3 version of the includeCommand4IDE extension.
3. Download the most recent version (0.2) of the datadriven.js extension.
4. **Merged** these files to new user-extensions.js file. This order is critical!
5. create an xml file which must contain all the data–input and output–for a single test case.
6. Utilize your .xml file
7. Use Selenium-IDE or an editor to create an HTML test suite that includes your data-driven test as one of the tests to be executed.
8. Execute a command line:

> -jar selenium-server.jar
>
> ```
>     -userExtensions user-extensions.js
>     -htmlSuite 
>        "*chrome" 
>        "`<base URL>`" 
>        "`<Selenium test suite file>`" 
>        "`<results log file>`"  
>    -timeout nnnn
> ```

I don't post all steps. I think these steps are important for create data-driven testing from a Selenium-RC command line.  Please check all steps!

Perhaps its working on Ubuntu OS, if its works on Windows. Two popup window is weird for me, but may be not is problem. I can only offer check these points:

- create suite.html with firefox selenium IDE
- try to use ***chrome** in command line.
- Please check order of scripts in user-extensions.js file.

I hope it helps!

Comment: thank @herry , I think includeCommand4IDE does not work with selenese tests

Comment: how to give timeout and speed as slow and auto= false?

Comment: @Rahul timeout parameter is contain above script. Speed control you can define in [IDE or code](http://seleniumforum.forumotion.net/t1147-how-to-set-speed-for-my-selenium-test). But it wouldn't be work for Webdriver.